# How to follow DRY principle in Go in function?

Tags: go, dry

I have this function to find the first Account that satisfies a predicate.

```
func findAccount(accounts []Account, f func(Account) bool) (*Account, error) {
    for _, account := range accounts {
        if f(account) {
            return &account, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, ErrNoSuchAccount
}
```

and another function to find the first Team that satisfies a predicate.

```
func findTeam(teams []Team, f func(Team) bool) (*Team, error) {
    for _, team := range teams {
        if f(team) {
            return &team, nil
        }
    }
    return nil, ErrNoSuchTeam
}
```

To DRY, I wonder if they can be combined as most lines of the routines are identical.

Comment: You can try to find commonality for the `Account` and `Team` types through an interface.

Comment: Most lines aren't identical, as they operate on and return different types. If it makes sense to have different types for Team and Account, and no common interface between them, then there's nothing to combine.

Comment: agreed, this is not repeating yourself. go is just verbose. if you want fewer characters in your source code use ruby

Comment: There is no need to DRY things which aren't wet.

Comment: Cool thanks.  Coming from a Scala background, seems it's totally different in Go.